# In Yajurveda there is written “Naasptimasti” means there is no idol of god and still we do worship of idols?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, yajur-veda, idols

I was told that in Yajurveda it is clearly written “NAASPTIMASTI” means don’t make idols. Still people do, why ?

And in Gita, they mentioned that make idols of god.

Can anyone tell me this?

Comment: Also take a look at this answer of mine for " Still we do worship of idols -https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17862/5620

Comment: Please check my comment in the below answer in case this hasn’t tagged you correctly

Answer (score 2):

In Hinduism God is considered as both Sakara (with form) and Nirakara (without form). So, Saguna worship and Nirguna worship both are prescribed.

For example, [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24825/how-does-arya-samaj-intepret-brihadaranyaka-upanishad-2-3-1) quotes a verse from the Brihad Aranyaka Upanishad, which clarifies that God is Amurta (without a form/murti) and at the same time Murta (with a form).

> dve vāva brahmaṇo rūpe, **mūrtaṃ caivāmūrtaṃ ca**
>
> English Translation: God (Brahman) has two modes, **formless
> (nirakara, asambhuta) as well as form (sakara, sambhuta).**
>
> 2.3.1

Hinduism is a practical religion. Ultimate goal in it is achieving Moksha but that is not possible to achieve without some form of worship or Upasana being performed. Now, it is not possible either to adopt the Nirguna worship mode from the start by any spiritual aspirant. And, that's why scriptures recommend to begin the Sadhana by contemplating on God having features.

For example, the Kularnava Tantram specifically says that it's for the benefit of the aspirants only that the formless God has been assigned features.

> UpAsakAnAm karyArthAm brahmano rupakalpnA.
>
> For the benefits of the upAsaka the formless Brahman has been
> assigned a form.

You can read more similar verses quoted in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20471/4732).

So, although it is mentioned in various scriptures (like in Kularnava and others) that Murti Puja is a lower form of worship it is not prohibited. Because it is a starting point that leads the aspirant to the higher forms of worship.

Comment: @rajatsharma, if you’re satisfied with this answer, you may want to accept it by pressing the tick button, below the voting arrows. That’s how the site functions and one knows about the answer being satisfactory. Also if you like it, you might want to upvote by pressing the up arrow on the answer. Thank you.