# If God is omnipresent, why do we need to invoke him?

Tags: gods, rituals

If God is omnipresent, why do we need to invoke him?

If one of the qualities of the Lord is that He is Omnipresent, then why do we still need to invoke His presence at certain prayers and rituals?

Comment: Omnipresent god without any shape and form can not be worshipped that is why we need to invoke him in a finite object .. either in fire or in water or in images or idols.

Comment: I think the following answer specifically answers your query -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20471/4732